# Why am I able to reference an outer queries columns from within a subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would expect that if I write a subquery then the columns available in the
main query would be unavailable in the subquery.  This doesn't seem to be
the case and I don't understand why.

Take the following example tables and query:

```
CREATE TABLE test_1 (
    col_a TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE test_2 (
    col_b TEXT
);

INSERT INTO test_1
VALUES
    ('Bob'),
    ('Tim')
;

INSERT INTO test_2
VALUES
    ('Sam'),
    ('Tim')
;

SELECT
    col_a
FROM
    test_1
WHERE col_a IN (SELECT col_a FROM test_2);
```

In the subquery `SELECT col_a FROM test_2` I would expect to get an error because `col_a` doesn't exist in the table `test_2`.  Instead the subquery returns the contents of `col_a` from `table_1`.

The output I get is:

```
 col_a
-------
 Bob
 Tim
```

I'm running the following version of PostgreSQL:

```
PostgreSQL 9.5.13 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Subqueries would be of vastly less usefulness if you couldn't do that (for less contrived examples, i.e. where the outer column being selected was of relevance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have multiple tables in a query, *always* use qualified table names.  You think the query is doing:

```
SELECT t1.col_a
FROM test_1 t1
WHERE t1.col_a IN (SELECT t2.col_a FROM test_2 t2);
```

This would generate an error, because `t2.col_a` does not exist.

However, the scoping rules for subqueries say that if the column is not in the subquery, look in the outer query.  So, if `t2.col_a` does not exist, then the query turns into:

```
SELECT t1.col_a
FROM test_1 t1
WHERE t1.col_a IN (SELECT t1.col_a FROM test_2 t2);
```

The solution is to qualify all column references so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: "You think the query is doing: ..." I read the OP like they exactly didn't expect what you think they expected but the "opposite, but they wonder why this doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @stickybit . . . Yes, the first query is what the OP expects.  It wasn't clear that this would generate an error, but I added that explanation into the answer.  The explanation in the first OP's first paragraph is a bit . . . vague, but the rest of the question is rather clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you, that was helpful.  Do you know where I could find documentation on those scoping rules?  I've looked through what I thought were the relevant portion of the PostgreSQL manual but couldn't find anything.